# Text color in prompt over SearchBar

Tags: iphone, xcode, colors, prompt, searchbar

I want to have a text in the prompt over the SearchBar. I use the XIB to set the Search Bar.
And as I want to have the SearchBar in a darker color than default, the text seems not to adapt to the change of color and is too dark to be readable. No setting in the xib to change text color what I can see.
Anybody who knows to fix this?
Not very important but would be nice because it looks nicer with the color I want.

Comment: There's actually a separate 'prompt' property nowadays which makes this question potentially really confusing — the placeholder is a different thing altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
searchBar.delegate = self;
searchBar.placeholder = @"Search";
searchBar.text = @"";
searchBar.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
searchBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:127/255.0f green:163/255.0f blue: alpha:1.0f];
```

Comment: But it doesn't seem to work in combination with the IB. Programmatically overrides the xib and the code does not deal with the prompt text color. I have difficulties to get my search work if I have to set the delegates myself by code. Guess I don't fully know how to do that by code at the same way xib does it for me.